# apply multiple filters on a List (Flutter)

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a method in my Provider to filter a list of Object  :

```
  List<Meal> applyFilter(bool snack, bool breakfast, bool dinner, bool lunch) {


      if (breakfast == true) {
      return _meals.where((element) => element.isBreakfast).toList();
    }
    if (snack == true) {
      return _meals.where((element) => element.isSnack).toList();
    }

    if (dinner == true) {
      return _meals.where((element) => element.isDinner).toList();
    }

    if (lunch == true) {
      return _meals.where((element) => element.isLunch).toList();
    }

    return _meals;
  }
```

and in my MainScreen I have a ListView builder like this here I have whole items in my list :

```
class _DietAvailableMealsState extends State<DietAvailableMeals> {
  bool _breakFast = false;
  bool _isSelected = false;
  bool _snack = false;
  bool _dinner = false;
  bool _lunch = false;

@override

Widget build(BuildContext context) {
final mealsList = Provider.of<Meals>(context, listen: false);
List<Meal> customList = mealsList.applyFilter(_snack, _breakFast, _dinner, _lunch);

return Expanded(child:
istView.builder(
itemBuilder: (ctx, index) =>MealCard(customList[index]),
itemCount: customList.length,
),
);
```

now in my MainScreen I have some FilterChip I want to apply my method on this list and return a new list based on chosen filter  :

```
FilterChip(
      label: Text(widget.chipName),
      selected:_isSelected,
      
      backgroundColor: Colors.purple[50],
      selectedColor: customGreen,
      onSelected: (selected) {
        setState(() {

          _isSelected = selected;
         
           _snack = !snack
          
           
        
      
        });
      },
    );
```

everything works fine but I can't apply multiple filters for example when I choose Snack & Breakfast chip together I've got only breakfast list. It seems like a Choice chip not a FilterChip.

Answer (score 1):

that's because you return from the function when you apply any filter,
try removing the `return` from every condition, create a list to apply the filters to, then return that list.

```
 List<Meal> applyFilter(bool snack, bool breakfast, bool dinner, bool lunch) {

    // cloned _meals into a new list to avoid changing the data in _meals
    List<Meal> filteredList = List.from(_meals);

    if (breakfast == true) {
      // remove every element that does not satisfy the condition 
      filteredList.removeWhere((element) => !element.isBreakfast);
    }
    if (snack == true) {
      filteredList.removeWhere((element) => !element.isSnack);
    }

    if (dinner == true) {
      filteredList.removeWhere((element) => !element.isDinner);
    }

    if (lunch == true) {
      filteredList.removeWhere((element) => !element.isLunch);
    }

    return filteredList;
  }
```

Comment: Your code doesn't do anything with the results of each `_meals.where(..).toList()`, so there will be no net effect.

Comment: @jamesdlin yes It doesn't work would you explain how should I apply that filter??

Comment: @Behnam 1. Add a local variable: `var meals = _meals;` . 2. Do `meals = meals.where(...).toList();` everywhere. 3. At the end, do `_meals = meals; return meals;`. (However, I personally think that your function *either* should do `return meals` (leaving `_meals` alone) *or* should set `_meals = meals` and return nothing (with a `void` return type).  Doing both is redundant and weird.

Comment: @MichaelSoliman still I can't get result with this logic

Comment: @Behnam okay check this last update